# Updated array needs to be set with react hooks but creates infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-hooks, react-state

in my code below I am fetching images from Firebase Firestore. The url is returned properly and is pushed to the `images state`

Now the problem is that identical urls are being added (because the `useEffect` runs to soon or early?)

So in the second `useEffect` i update the images array and remove duplicates nice and easy with `...new Set`, but the problem is that `setImages()` is also called there which is not allowed since this creates the infinite loop.

So my question is, can someone tell me where to set the `updated array uniq` to the `images state` the right way?

Thanks in advance!

```
const [evtsFiltered, setEvtsFiltered] = useState([])
const [images, setImages] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
    evtsFiltered?.map((item) => {
      storageRef
        .child(item)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          setImages((images) => [...images, url]) // url returns a plain string such as 'http://image-1.png'
        })
    })
  }, [evtsFiltered])

  useEffect(() => {
    let uniq = [...new Set(images)] // Duplicates are removed
    setImages(uniq) // Infinite loop problem
  }, [images])
```

Comment: Why not do the `...new Set(images)` bit inside your first `useEffect` only when using `setImages` ? The second `useEffect` is bound to run repeatedly since you're changing the value which retriggers that `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvements needed in your code:

- You don't need to use `optional-chaining` with `evtsFiltered` because its initial value is an empty array.
- `map()` is not the right method to use if you are just going to iterate over the array. You could use `map()` method along with `Promise.all()` to fetch image URLs.
- Identical URLs could not be because of `useEffect` hook. Either you have duplicate URLs in the firebase storage or you are not updating the state correctly.
- You wouldn't need the second `useEffect` hook if you update the `images` state correctly in the first `useEffect` hook.

Try updating the state using `Promise.all()` and `map()` method as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const arr = evtsFiltered.map((item) => {
       return storageRef.child(item).getDownloadURL();          
    });

   Promise.all(arr)
     .then(urls => {
        setImages(urls);
     })
     .catch(err => /* handle error */ );
    
}, [evtsFiltered]);
```

Using `map()` method, create an array of promises that you can then resolve using `Promise.all()` method. Also, remove the 2nd `useEffect` hook.

Comment: thanks for looking into it, this returns the correct images without duplicates. So it's because Promise.all waits until it is finished and only than updates state? Thanks for the other tips as well.

Comment: `Promise.all` takes an array of promises and once all the promises fulfil, only then it invokes the `then()` method's callback function. Using `Promise.all`, `setImages()` is only called once with all the urls.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you try to update state on which you listen tov updated. One solution is to create another state which contains unique images.

```
const [evtsFiltered, setEvtsFiltered] = useState([])
const [images, setImages] = useState([])
const [uniqueImages, setUniqueImages] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
    evtsFiltered?.map((item) => {
      storageRef
        .child(item)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          setImages((images) => [...images, url]) // url returns a plain string such as 'http://image-1.png'
        })
    })
  }, [evtsFiltered])

  useEffect(() => {
    let uniq = [...new Set(images)] // Duplicates are removed
    setUniqueImages(uniq) // Infinite loop problem
  }, [images])
```

Another to set unique images just in first effect.

```
.then((url) => {
          setImages((images) => [ ...new Set([ ...images, url])]) // url returns a plain string such as 'http://image-1.png'
})
```

Comment: Hi Tomasz, Youssaf's answer solved my problem, but thanks for looking into it! Cheers